# Can I change my starting spot before a race begins?

Tags: forza-horizon-2

In almost every single player championship race I'm in, I have started in or near last place.   It becomes a pain to navigate around the AI (especially when they brake-check you) when racing.   Is there anyway I can start in 1st place before the race begins?

Comment: In singleplayer championships? online races? Or just all of them. In singleplayer I always start in 8th place out of 12. Do you start differently?

Comment: Sorry I will be a little bit more specific - Single player championships.   I usually start 10-12th place.  -> edited

Comment: what difficulty are you on?

Comment: @Rapitor Once I am off work, I can let you know.  I'm pretty sure its normal, no assist braking, full lines, ABS.... If I am missing something, I can update it later today

Answer (score 1):

To answer you question simply: do worse.

The reason you are placed so far back in the starting queue is to add the challenge of getting past the cars in front of you. The better you do, the further back in the starting queue you will be placed.

It works in reverse too: if you do worse, your place will move further toward the front, to remove the (initial) challenge of the other racers.

Comment: I'm not sure about this. As I said in my comment my starting position has always been 8th and I get 1st nearly every race. if not 2nd.

Comment: I am with @Rapitor on this... Do you have a source ?

Comment: @Rapitor that's my point. The better you do in previous races the further back in the starting line you will be placed. You may not go all the way back to last place, but it's (like I said) to add challenge.

Comment: @ZeroStack Unfortunately no, I don't have a source, only from experience.